# Undefined now() error in my code

Tags: php

```
$sql="INSERT into payment_in('Date','name','value') values('".now()."','".$a."',".$b.")";'
```

using now function in above code give me an undefined function error

Comment: NOW() is a mysql function, not php function.

Comment: your quotes are also wrong.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as @JohnConde has mentioned, `NOW()` is a MySQL function, not a PHP function.

And second, use backticks to wrap the table and column names and use quotes to wrap your strings. Backticks are only necessary when the table name or column name is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).

So your query should be like this:

```
$sql="INSERT into `payment_in`(`Date`, `name`, `value`) VALUES(NOW(),'" . $a . "', '". $b . "')";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql="INSERT into payment_in('Date','name','value') values(now(),'".$a."',".$b.")";'
```

(Make sure $a and $b are coming from reliable sources or you are exposed to a security hack called SQL Injection.  See http://www.wikihow.com/Prevent-SQL-Injection-in-PHP)